# Problems with Object Oriented Programming with Processing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, processing

So I'm desperately trying to cut my little program I made in Processing into different classes. However I fail on the basic level...

**The Project:**
We need to program a little game in Processing as the final test of our semester. Problem is, we mostly learn how to do stuff in Processing's editor. However in my opinion it's pretty bugged and the fact it has a *pre-compiler* from Processing to Java bothers me as well.

**The Problem:**
So I try using Eclipse instead. With the provided tutorial by on Processing's website I came pretty well along writing the pure Java code instead of the simplified Processing Syntax. However when it comes to making a second class, I'm completely lost. We also learn in university how to code in Java and we just finished object oriented programming as a topic. However we do not learn how to connect it with Processing.

**The Problem-Code:**
Below you can find my code I got problems with. I cut out most of the unneccessary stuff. However I've uploaded the full code to Pastebin, if you want to see it (**warning:** very messy).

main:

```
import processing.core.*;

public class animation extends PApplet{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main("animation");
    }

    controls keyboard;

    //some variable initializations

    public void setup() {

        frameRate(60);

    }

    public void settings() {

        //some settings stuff

    }

    //some more variables

    boolean moving = false,
            //triggered = false;

    boolean goUp, goDown, goLeft, goRight;

    //more vars

    public void draw() {

        //unneccesary code for drawing all the stuff

        moving = false;


        keyboard.check();

        if(keyboard.goUp) {
            if(ypos > 0) {
                moving = true;
                ypos = ypos - speed * 100 * elapTime;
            }
        }

        if(keyboard.goDown) {
            if(ypos < height - images[0].height) {
                moving = true;
                ypos = ypos + speed * 100 * elapTime;
            }
        }

        if(keyboard.goLeft) {
            if(xpos > 0) {
                dir = 1;
                moving = true;
                xpos = xpos - speed * 100 * elapTime;
            }
        }

        if(keyboard.goRight) {
            if(xpos < width - images[0].width) {
                dir = -1;
                moving = true;
                xpos = xpos + speed * 100 * elapTime;
            }
        }

        if(keyPressed && key == 't' && !triggered) {
            triggered = true;
        }

    }

}
```

[full code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Nf6a83jD)

controls:

```
public class controls extends animation {

    boolean goUp, goDown, goLeft, goRight;

    public void check() {

        keyPressed();
        keyReleased();

    }

    public void keyPressed() {
        setMove(keyCode, true);
    }

    public void keyReleased() {
        setMove(keyCode, false);
    }

    boolean setMove(int key, boolean b) {

        switch (key) {

        case UP:

            return goUp = b;

        case DOWN:

            return goDown = b;

        case LEFT:

            return goLeft = b;

        case RIGHT:

            return goRight = b;

        default:

            return b;

        }

    }

}
```

[full code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cJM4t2UM)

**The error log:**

```
#// loaded 'data/harambe/frame0.png'
#// loaded 'data/harambe/frame1.png'
#// loaded 'data/harambe/frame2.png'
#// loaded 'data/harambe/frame3.png'
#// loaded 'data/harambe/frame4.png'
#// loaded 'data/harambe/frame5.png'
#// loaded 'data/harambe/frame6.png'
#// loaded 'data/harambe/frame7.png'
#// loaded 'data/harambe/frame8.png'
#// loaded 'data/harambe/frame9.png'
#// loaded 'data/harambe/frame10.png'
#// loaded 'data/harambe/frame11.png'
#// loaded 'data/harambe/frame12.png'
#// loaded 'data/harambe/frame13.png'
#// LOADED ALL DATA

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at animation.draw(animation.java:120)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2412)
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL$DrawListener.display(PSurfaceJOGL.java:880)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:692)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:674)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase$2.run(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:443)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1293)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1147)
    at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.display(GLWindow.java:759)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:81)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.display(AnimatorBase.java:452)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$MainTask.run(FPSAnimator.java:178)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance to everyone who is willing to try solving this problem. I'm really lost at this point and tried a lot of things...

**EDIT:** When I change `controls keyboard` to `controls keyboard = new controls();` i get the following error log (java.lang.StackOverflowError):

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at controls.<init>(controls.java:1)
    at animation.<init>(animation.java:9)
    at controls.<init>(controls.java:1)
    at animation.<init>(animation.java:9)
    at controls.<init>(controls.java:1)
   at animation.<init>(animation.java:9)
```

Above errors repeat VERY often

Comment: In  `animation` , you never initialized `keyboard`, so it is `null`.

Comment: You mean like `controls keyboard = new controls();`? This gives me an even longer error log ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/P7issAdc))

Comment: Do you really need `controls` to extend `animation` ? Because here you have an infinite stack of calls : animation creates a controls which is an animation which creates a controls, etc...

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I need it because I want to continue developing on this prototype (this will be a game at some point) so it will consist of multiple classes. `main` will shrink and shring till I organzied most of it into classes. But what do you mean with the call-loop? What mistake have I made?

Comment: When you call `new animation()` _(start of the loop)_, its fields get initialized, so it creates a `new controls()`. `controls` extends `animation`, so `new controls()` will call `new animation()`, so you're back to the _start of the loop_, and are looping on these calls forever.

Comment: Ok, that definetly makes sense. But is it actually possible to properly write a class in eclipse for processing?

Comment: It looks to me that you'd better use composition and not inheritance in that case. `animation` _has_ `controls` , `controls` _is not_ an `animation` .So I'd juste remove the inheritance between those two objects.

Comment: You mean by removing `extends animation` and handling it as a class on it's own? Well... I think I'm trying things here that are way too complicated for me. i may should ask my professor about this.

Comment: Yes reconsider your logical class hierarchy, and don't hesitate as you said, to ask your professor for clarifications.

Comment: Did you get this sorted out, or did you still have a question?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Yes I did! Since I posted this question a huge step forward has been made and the game has now about 7 classes, uses different libaries and so on. I learned a lot in the past weeks. Thank you anyways for trying to help me ;)